# is it possible to have boost::optional of a class and call its member functions?

Tags: boost, option-type

I tried using boost optional and it works nice, but I cant find a way to call the member functions of the wrapped type. Is that by design or? I guess so because calling member funcs of unitialized boost::optional variable would be bad, but I want to be 100% sure.

```
class test
{
    int test_method()
    {
        return 1984;
    }
};
test tst;
boost::optional<test> get_test()
{
    boost::optional<test> result(tst);
    return result;
}


// main

    boost::optional <test> ret_val= get_test();
    int x=ret_val.test_method();
```

> ‘class boost::optional ANGLE_BRACKET test ANGLE_BRACKET ’ has no member named ‘test_method’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ret_val->test_method()` instead; `operator->` can access the contained object in a `boost::optional`.  Note that you need to ensure that the `optional` is not empty before you do that.

Comment: it works, but this -> part is confusing me, how would you access for example ->second of the boost::optional<std::map<int,int>::iterator>  ?

Comment: `(*ret_val)->second` or `ret_val.get()->second`